# PHP/MySQL printing 0 inside of int value

Tags: php, mysql, printf

When I try to enter in an ID field to tag my individual posts (post-id:1932, etc.), the value always prints as 0, instead of the database's value.

The query takes the $_REQUEST's topic variable (generated from clicking a link).

Here is my code:

```
 <?php

 require_once 'connect.php';

 $topic = $_REQUEST['topic'];

 // Build the SELECT statement
 $select_posts =
 "SELECT p.topic, p.title, p.pic_id, p.snippet, p.content, p.author_id, p.date FROM posts p WHERE p.topic =  '" . $topic . "' OR p.topic='Admin' ORDER BY p.date DESC";

 // Run the Query
 $result = mysql_query($select_posts);

 ?>

 <?php
   $post_count=0;
   while ($post_count<10 && $posts = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $posts_row = sprintf(
           '<entry>
               <headline>%s</headline>
                    <pic><img class=inlinepic src=/Sustenance/assets/post-pics/%d.jpg></pic>
                    <snippet class=on id="%d snippet">%s</snippet>
                    <readmore id="readmore%d" class=on onclick=readmore("%d")>Read More</readmore>
                    <content id="%d" class="less">%s
                        <readmore class=on onclick=readless(%d)>Show Less</readmore>
                    </content>
                    <byline>
                        <by>by</by>
                        <author>%s</author>
                    </byline>
            </entry>',
       $posts['topic'], $posts['title'], $posts['pic_id'], $posts['post_id'], $posts['snippet'], $posts['post_id'], $posts['post_id'], $posts['post_id'], $posts['content'], $posts['post_id'], $posts['author_id']);
       echo $posts_row;
       $post_count++;
  }
 ?>
```

What I find odd is the 'pic_id' prints properly and pulls in the correct picture, but even when I tried to reuse the pic_id in the $divid it doesn't work. I've tried replacing the $divid with $posts['id'], using all the different integer type specifiers in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), and even using inline php.

Do I have a syntax error? Why does it keep printing out 0?

EDIT: I have posted the query as per requested

EDIT 2: Removed the $divid variable.

Comment: shouldn't  *$divid=$posts['post_id'];* be _inside_ the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to put the line

```
$divid=$posts['post_id'];
```

inside your `while` loop. The way it is now it tries to get a value of `$posts['post_id']` already before it is assigned for the first time in the loop head and therefore is `0` and never changes (since it's never reassigned).

Comment: That is an excellent point! I moved it back to where it ought to be. However, that didn't seem to fix the problem.